# iOS 11 - Is in app purchase testing using a sandbox user keeps asking to sign in for anyone else too? Forever loop?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, ios11

I am testing a non-consumable IAP on an iPhone 6s running iOS 11 GM.
Whenever I tap my "Buy" button, it asks me to sign in. I tap "Sign in with existing apple ID" and enter my sandbox user details (which worked fine as of a few days ago on iOS 10).

After entering, it just goes back to the same "Sign in" screen. I tried entering a few more times and it just goes back to the same screen again. Keeps looping forever.

Is this down for anyone else?

Comment: Did you solved this? I encounter same behaviour with official iOS 11 release...

Comment: @MiroslavHrivik yes I ended up creating a new sandbox user and that worked. Make sure to sign out of App Store before and do not sign in with sandbox user in App Store, only sign in from the app itself when it prompts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The same thing happens for me, for three separate sandbox users which were created before iOS 11 release. (The problem seems prevalent on iOS 11, there are posts on reddit and apple forums reporting this issue)

It seems creating new fresh sandbox user is the way to go. Sandbox users created after iOS 11 release work, while those created before the release cause "Sign in/Create Apple id" alert loop.

Comment: The new account worked for 3 days and then started having the same problem again this morning. Created another new account again and that’s working again. No clue why.

Answer (score 13):

I did this steps and it's works

- logout your account from iPhone
- create fresh sandbox account
- use the app to purchase anything - it will ask you for your login information
- put the fresh sandbox account - it will ask you again your login information
- leave the message and close the app
- open the app again and try to purchase anything and it will works ^^"

Comment: Did almost the same steps for macOS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46592844/4514671

Answer (score 8):

### **Fixed as follows**

1. Create **new sandbox** account.
2. Logout iTunes account from device setting.
3. Try to purchase and enter new sandbox account when popup appears.

> **NOTE:** It may not work first time, I entered account twice & it worked second time.

**If it does not work after few day try new account.**

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings ▸ iTunes & Appstore** scroll to bottom.

You can add account here for sand box purchase.

For iOS 11 and older, sign out the existing account if any. For iOS 12 and newer do not sign out of your Apple account - but manage it at the bottom of the page mentioned above.

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchase_transactions

To keep the sandbox account operational, be sure to only use it when you see `[Environment: Sandbox]` on the login prompt. For all sandbox accounts, you still have to go through the email-verification process (click link in email).

Comment: Excellent! The sandbox account being used is shown all the way at the bottom of that screen. I could not find where to "control your sandbox account directly on-device in Settings". For iOS 11 and below you had to sign out of your account. For iOS 12+ you no longer have to do this, just make sure you see `[Environment: Sandbox]` on the login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is what just worked for me.

1) Go to setting on your device and sign out of your current account. Then sign in with your Sandbox account.

2) Power off your device and when it boots in open the app you are testing. It may ask for you to enter in you password (which would be the sandbox user's password)

This should fix the issue...

Let me know if you tried and the outcome.