# IAP doesn't work with iOS 11 for the sandbox store

Tags: ios

Last week I updated an iPhone from iOS 10 to iOS 11 GM. After doing that I was no longer able to make purchases with the sandbox store (i.e. using a sandbox apple id) on that device (but could continue to do so on other devices that were still iOS 10).

Now iOS 11 is officially released today, so I updated another iPhone to it and its the same situation - IAP purchases using a sandbox Apple id don't work - the login dialog is displayed twice (its only once with iOS 10) and then the purchase fails with "Purchase fails with "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".

Is anybody else experiencing similar problems?

How is one supposed to test IAP with iOS 11 if sandbox ids isn't working?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257633/ios-11-is-in-app-purchase-testing-using-a-sandbox-user-keeps-asking-to-sign-in

Answer (score 4):

There's a thread on this on the Apple forum. Its affecting lots of people. Apple have not fixed it despite it being reported as a bug.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/261368#261368

UPDATE: Got fixed in an iOS 11.n update

Comment: Link is broken.