# Cannot test in-app purchases in Xcode 9 for macOS app

Tags: macos, testing, in-app-purchase, xcode9, mac-app-store

As of the release of iOS11 it has been a pain (if not impossible) testing in-app purchases. While I've found a great workaround for testing on iOS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467498/4514671 I could not find anything for macOS apps.

Answer (score 5):

So here is what I did that kind of does the same as with the iOS workaround:

1. In the App Store app Sign Out of your account (Store/Sign Out)
2. In iTunes Connect create a brand new Tester
3. Restart your computer
4. Open your Xcode project
5. Build & run
6. Click on your Buy button to start a purchase
7. Sign in with your newly created test account

[image: Sign in]

8. When prompted to Change the store click on Cancel

[image: Click Cancel]

9. Click on your Buy button to start a purchase again and the correct Buy Alert will pop up; finish the transaction by actually making the purchase

[image: Click Buy]

Done! **Hours of frustration saved!** Thanks Apple :[

Comment: I am converting my application form iphone to macOs.
subscription is working on the iphone fine but when i test the sample bundleID on macOs then  subscription is done..but receipt is not fetched from the appstore.
when i relaunch application then user is not premium because receipt is not found.
application is not able to download the receipt.
can you please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately step 7 (sign in) does not happen to me, even though I logged out of the App Store and restarted. For me it goes straight to "Account Not In This Store" after clicking "buy". Any idea?